# How to use arrays to search for folders and match it to the directory?

Tags: python, scripting, html-lists

I am trying to search for folders given in a text file and search it in a given directory and search for that specific folder.

The numbers in text(C:\Script\text.txt) file are as follows:
418956
456897
534867

And the folders that are I am trying to match with those numbers are in following order:
C:\Script\Box\Ram, Mae 418956
C:\Script\Box\Yang, Jin 456897
C:\Script\Box\Wang, Sing 534867

```
import os
import fnmatch

path = 'C:\Script\Box'

#read line into array 
arr = []
inp = open ("C:\Script\text.txt","r")
for line in inp.readlines():  
    for i in line.split():  
        arr.append(int(i))

folders = []
for (path, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    folders.extend(os.path.join(path, name) for name in dirnames)

if arr == folders
    print "Folder Found";

else:
    print "Folder Not Found";
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: `arr` is an array of integers, while `folders` is an array of strings.  They can never be equal.

Comment: Can arr be turned  into strings so that it is comparable?

Comment: 1. Make arr a `set`
2. When you are adding path to folders, check `if name in arr`
3. Finally, check the length of `arr` and `folders` for equality

Comment: @spicavigo How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import fnmatch

path = 'C:\Script\Box'

#read line into array 
arr = set()
inp = open ("C:\Script\text.txt","r")
for line in inp.readlines():  
    for i in line.split():  
        arr.add(i)

folders = []
for (path, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    folders.extend([os.path.join(path, name) for name in dirnames if name in arr])

if len(arr) == len(folders)
    print "All Folders Found"

else:
    print "All Folder Not Found"
    print folders
```